# Создание jquery функции

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет. Есть следующая функция:

```
function changeCount(current, next, selector) {
    $(function () {                     
        $({numberValue: current}).animate({numberValue: next}, { 
            duration: 500, 
            easing: "linear", 
            step: function(val) {  
                $(selector).html(Math.ceil(val)); 
            } 
        });
    }); 
}
```

Действие очень простое - анимация смены цифр. Вопрос: как ее преобразовать в:

```
(function( $ ){

  $.fn.changeNumbers = function(next) {

  };

})(jQuery);
```

Т.е. чтобы в коде к ней можно было обращаться по `$(selector).changeNumbers(current, next)`

Сделал такое:

```
(function( $ ){

      $.fn.changeNumbers = function(next) {
          $({numberValue: this.text()}).animate({numberValue: next}, { 
            duration: 500, 
            easing: "linear", 
            step: function(val) {  
                $(this).html(Math.ceil(val)); 
            } 
        });
      };

    })(jQuery);
```

Но выдает ошибку `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined` в строке `$(this).html(Math.ceil(val));`

Не до конца понимаю контекст this в создании функций, первый раз делаю что-то свое по jquery. Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В обработчике `step` `this` указывает не на исходный элемент, а на сконструированный объект `{numberValue: this.text()}`

Вам нужно перед запуском `animate` сохранить `this` в локальную переменную и в обработчике `step` обращаться к этой переменной

И еще, в jQuery принято строить цепочки вызовов. Поэтому будет здорово, если Вы вернете переданный `this` в функцию `changeNumbers` обратно

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.changeNumbers = function(next) {
    var obj = this;
    $({numberValue: this.text()}).animate({numberValue: next}, {
      duration: 500,
      easing: "linear",
      step: function(val) {
        obj.html(Math.ceil(val));
      }
    });
    return this;
  };
})(jQuery);

jQuery(function($) {
  $('#btn').click(function() {
    $('#num').text(50).changeNumbers(100).css({"background-color": "yellow"});
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="num">50</div>
<button id="btn">Go</button>
```